# RegisterStartupScript not working in C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I have two methods in my c# code. One is to open a error window and another is to close the error window.
The Problem is in the first method new window opened correctly, For the next method call(to close the window) sometimes window is not getting closed.

Here my first method code to open the window

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
Type cstype = this.GetType();
string script = "window['myWindow'] = window.open('Error.aspx', 'myWindow', 'width=400,height=200');";
cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "OpenScript", script, true);
```

My second method to close the window

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
Type cstype = this.GetType();
string script = "var myWindow=window['myWindow']; if(myWindow == null){";
script += "myWindow = window.open('', 'myWindow');}";
script += "myWindow.close();";
cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "CloseScript", script, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just check `if (myWindow != null) {` first in your javascript in the second method and then close  the window with `myWindow.close();` and not the opposite. Why are you also using `window.open('','myWindow');` in the second method?

The second method should be as shown here:

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
Type cstype = this.GetType();
string script = "var myWindow=window['myWindow']; if(myWindow != null)";
script += "myWindow.close();";
cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "CloseScript", script, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..  most of the time var myWindow =window['myWindow'] returns null or undefined. While checking if(myWindow != null) it always skipping  myWindow.close(). So if there is no object reference assigned to var myWindow, window.open('','myWindow') opens the window and closing the same.

Comment: I am not sure whatever the reason you have nulls and undefined in 'myWindow' variable but either way to handle these situations you can add the following line to your if statement in method 2
`if (myWindow != null || typeof(myWindow) === 'null' || typeof(myWindow) === 'undefined')`
Let me know if that is suitable for this problem.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment above:
`if (myWindow === null || typeof(myWindow) === 'undefined')`